# Can I force WPF rendering tier?

Tags: wpf

Is there any way I can force WPF rendering tiers mentioned here? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx

For example I am on tier 2, but I want to simulate the application in tier 1 or 0 scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by modifying the registry on your system.

In general, you'll want to turn on the reference rasterizer or disable hardware acceleration.

For details, see MSDN's page for [Graphics Rendering Registry Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could force tier-0 by just turning on window transparency.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?